# Samsung 43" CJ89 Dual input height difference issue

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport

I recently got myself a Samsung 43" CJ89 Super Ultrawide screen and I love it, but one thing is bugging the crap out of me. I use this monitor mainly for working activities due to Corona and the software that is required to connect to the company does not support ultra-wide res settings. To solve this, I used an displayport and HDMI cable coming from the same PC to imitate 2 separate monitors.

This works as intended, but it has a slight side effect. For some reason, the HDMI output is placed slightly higher then the displayport output. It drives me nuts. Anyone experienced this as well? and more importantly, how can it be solved?
[image]
[image: zoomed image]

Hardware specs:
Nvidia 970gtx Graphics card with driver version 27.21.14.5655
LC43CJ89 with default settings
Input1 = Displayport
Input2 = HDMI 1.4

My OCD thanks you in advance!

Edit:
Oke this is nuts... When i made the OP screenshot, Notepad had this slight height difference in the middle. Now when looking at the screenshot, Notepad looks fine, but the background image on the right is a bit lower.

That's just weird, right?

Comment: Your screens are misaligned in display settings.

Comment: I rearranged them several times, turned them around etc. but this slight difference stays.